# Conventions on subscripts and superscripts: "Math mode" or "text mode" for (relatively long) words?

Tags: notation, convention, scientific-notation

Is there any mathematical convention on the *mode* of writing (relatively long) words in subscripts or superscripts, i.e. either with a Latex *math mode* or with a *text mode*?

For example:

- math mode: $A^{rotation}$
- text mode: $A^{\text{rotation}}$

Note: This question is related to mathematical conventions for scientific writing, even though it might overlap with the domain of Latex.

Comment: Math mode for words is never correct. Math mode spaces the letters much differently than text mode. One could imagine italics instead of roman font perhaps. I would try to avoid long words like this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GregMartin! Many thanks! I was thinking about the same, exactly for the space among the characters.... and, yes, I could write something shorter, like $A^{\text{rot}}$... As far as I understood, a (or any?) *text mode* would be the correct choice, instead of a *math mode*....